# How many reflexive but not antisymmetric relations are there?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

**Question:** How many reflexive but not antisymmetric relations are there on a set A containing n elements?

So N(reflexive but not antisymmetric) = N(reflexive functions) - N(reflexive and antisymmetric). The number of reflexive relations over A $2^{n^2-n}$, but how would I get the number of reflexive and antisymmetric relations over A? Thanks.

Comment: @5xum Ohh gosh, my bad. I meant relations. I have edited the question already. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is $3^{{n} \choose 2 }$.

Comment: To explain @Rohan 's *very short response*... for each two-element subset of $A$ decide which of the following occurs: it doesn't appear in the relation at all, it appears in the canonical order, it appears in the opposite to canonical order.  As there are three choices for each two-element subset and since exactly one of those three things will occur for each due to anti-symmetry, applying multiplication principle we get $3^{\binom{n}{2}}$ outcomes.

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A047656

Answer (score 3):

As has already been stated in the comments, the count is $3^{\binom n2}$: By reflexivity, the relation contains all pairs $(x,x)$, so no choices there. For $x\ne y$, it contains either $(x,y)$ or $(y,x)$ or neither, $3$ choices for each of the $\binom n2$ pairs.